# Error in method JSONParser.makeHttpResquest

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I'm trying to get some data from my database through php. When I test it in browser it shows me this output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
               (
            [den_prod] => Ciorb? de v?cu?? / Beef Soup (350 gr)
            [descriere] => legume, smântân? ?i ardei iute / vegetables, sour cream and hot pepper
            [pret] => 6
 )...and so on, but when I try to display this in a listView it gives me this error:

07-27 16:17:14.879: E/JSON Parser(2798): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value Array of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject and a null pointer exception on method makeHttpRequest.
```

I really don't know what to do next, I'm stuck in here. Thank you for your attention, I appreciate it.
My activity:

```
public class AllSoupsActivity extends Activity{

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> soupsList;

// url to get all products list
private static String url_all_soups = "http://10.0.2.2/android_connect/get_all_soups.php";

// JSON Node names
public static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "produs";
private static final String TAG_PRICE = "pret";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "prod_name";
private static final String TAG_DESCRIPTION="descriere";

// products JSONArray
JSONArray soups = null;
ListView lv;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.products_list);

    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
      .detectDiskReads().detectDiskWrites().detectNetwork() // StrictMode is most commonly used to catch accidental disk or network access on the application's main thread
      .penaltyLog().build());
    // Hashmap for ListView
    soupsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Loading products in Background Thread
    new LoadAllProducts().execute();

    // Get listview
    lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.product_list);

}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
 * */
class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        /*pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllSoupsActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();*/
    }

    /**
     * getting All products from url
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_soups, "POST", params);

        if(json==null) Log.d("=============","json nulllllllllllllll");
        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        //Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            Log.d("=================", "====="+success);
            if (success == 1) {
                // products found
                // Getting Array of Products
                soups = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);
                 if(soups==null) Log.d("===========","===============nullllll======");
                // looping through All Products
                for (int i = 0; i < soups.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject soup = soups.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String soupName = soup.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String description = soup.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION);
                    Double price=soup.getDouble(TAG_PRICE);
                    Log.d("=============","==========="+soupName+"====="+description+"======"+price);
                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, soupName);
                    map.put(TAG_DESCRIPTION, description);
                    map.put(TAG_PRICE, price.toString());

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    soupsList.add(map);
                }
            }else{
                Log.d("=========","raspunsul e alt numar");
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        //pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        AllSoupsActivity.this, soupsList,
                        R.layout.list_row_subcategory, new String[] { TAG_NAME,
                                TAG_DESCRIPTION, TAG_PRICE},
                        new int[] { R.id.denumire, R.id.descriere, R.id.pret });
                // updating listview
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });

    }

}
}
```

and here is my php file:

```
 <?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
$response=array();
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","re1st","mydb");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$result=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM produs, subcategorie where subcategorie.id_subcateg=produs.id_subcateg AND subcategorie.den_subcateg='Supe si Ciorbe / Soup and Sour Soup'");

if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
    $response["produs"]=array();
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            $soup=array();
            $soup["den_prod"]=$row["den_prod"];
            $soup["descriere"]=$row["descriere"];
            $soup["pret"]=$row["pret"];
            array_push($response["produs"], $soup);

            //print_r($response);
        }
    $response["success"]=1;
    $response["message"] = "All soups displayed from database.";
    echo json_encode($response);
    print_r($response["produs"]);
}else{
    $response["success"]=0;
    $response["message"]="No products found";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Also I want to mention that works to insert rows, but for some reason to fetch them it doesn't. Also in the logcat appers the log.d I've put that json is null from this line:

```
JSONObject json = JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_soups, "POST", params);
```

The JSONParser class I've taken it from this site http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/.

Comment: try removing `print_r($response["produs"]);` on the line after `echo json_encode($response);`

Comment: I did that, no result

Comment: the error was from the ? character. Apparently, this is how java reads the romanian characters like ă, ș, ț, â and î.